# При повторном открытии станицы не загружаются данные из Firebase

Tags: firebase, angular, ionic

Я новичок в Angular и Ionic. Как базу данных использую Firebase. 
В качестве примера использовала: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-firebase-angularfire/.
Структура, идентичная этому примеру, у меня работает без проблем. С проблемой столкнулась при создании своей структуры.
Есть страница 'My' - при ее загрузке должен загружать массив `MyAd[]` с фотографиями из Firebase.

```
myAdPhotos: MyAd[];

constructor(
  private myAdService: MyService,
  private loadingController: LoadingController
) {
  this.loadAd();
}

async loadAd(){
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading Ad..'
  });
  await loading.present();

  this.myAdService.getMyAds().subscribe(res => {
    this.myAdPhotos = res;
    loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

`myAdService` и `MyAd[]` соответствуют примеру с TODO.
При первом открытии страницы все загружается без ошибок. Но при нажатии кнопки назад и повторном открытии этой страницы открывается окошко `loading` и ничего не происходит. `this.myAdService.getMyAds()` не вызывается.

Надеюсь на помощь знающих людей и тех кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой. Мои поиски решения не увенчались успехом :_(

Answer (score 0):

Я советую вам изучить жизненный цикл компонента. 
[Lifecycle Ionic](http://lifecycle%20ionic%20(angular))

В вашем случае нужно убрать из constructor метод this.loadAd()

Вообще лучше вызывать все методы в ngOnInit()

Проблема у вас в том, что constructor и OnInit вызывается только при построении компонента, а так как при навигации ionic сохраняет состоянии компонента, то при возвращении на страницу методы OnInit и Constructor не вызываются.

Решение очень простое, использовать ionViewWillEnter или ionViewDidEnter (что вам больше подходит)
Пример:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
this.loadAd();
}
```